# How to use __attribute_format_arg__ on a function not returning a char* but a object around it wrapping it?

Tags: c

I have a function that looks kind of like this:

```
Exception* make_exception(Exception* caused_by, size_t caused_at, const char* format, ...) __attribute_format_arg__(3);
```

The `Exception` type is just a struct containing the result of the function.
I get the following error:

```
error: function does not return string type
```

Is there any way to fix this?

Comment: Note that your attribute is weird: `__attribute_format_arg__(3)` --> `__attribute__((format_arg(3)))` Also, `format_arg` _is_ a valid option, but you probably want `__printf__` as KamilCuk mentioned

Comment: The line I wrote in the question caused the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use:

```
#ifdef __GNUC__
__attribute__((__format__(__printf__, 3, 4)))
#endif
Exception* make_exception(Exception* caused_by, size_t caused_at, const char* format, ...);
```

See https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Common-Function-Attributes.html#Common-Function-Attributes .